# How to capture client-side missing resources?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to capture instances of missing resources by adding the following code snippet to my site's `<head>`:

```
window.onerror = function(message, file, line) {
    console.log('Error:', message, file, line);
}
```

But this only seems to capture JS errors, not general DOM errors. I've tried deliberately: 1) creating `<script>` tags pointing to  non-existent files, and 2) creating `<img>` tags pointing to non-existent images. Neither triggers an `error` event.

My questions are:

1. What sorts of errors is `onerror` listening for?
2. How do I capture these errors? Why isn't the above code working?

Comment: I am very interested in an answer to "What sort of errors is `onerror` listening for?". I know that it certainly doesn't catch everything.

Comment: My testing seems to indicate that the `error` event does not bubble, which is not exactly cool.

Comment: I don't want to say that this is not possible, but I'd like to point out that `monitorEvents(document)` (from the Chrome developer tools) shows no event for when an image fails to load. You're gonna have a very hard time with that, without specifying the `onerror` attribute for all resources you want to check.

Comment: What you're essentially looking for is when the server returns a 404: not found response for a given file rather than the 200: ok response, which is a server event really and will be stored in the server's logs.  If what you're trying to do is get a list of missing things when you go to a page, then the 'net' tab of firebug or a tool like Charles proxy will do that better.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a specific element that you think might have a non-existant image or script, and you don't need to catch things in general, you can add an `onerror` to those specific `img` or `script` tags:

```
<img src="http://something/that/might/not/exist.png" onerror="alert('Error!');">
```

Comment: I need to catch things in general. :-) Helpful, though.